# how to send post parameters from yii2 gridview

Tags: php, post, gridview, parameters, yii2

am new to yii2. I have been trying to send some parameters to an action from a view using the post method, unfortunately my action seems not to see/receive them. Help would be most appreciated.

my column action is something like this:

```
'buttons'=> [
    'password'=> function ($url, $model, $key){
    $url =$url = Url::toRoute(['users/reset-password', 'username' => $model->username]);
    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>',$url,[
                   'title'=>'Clave',
                   'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to change this password?'),
                   'data-method' => 'post',
                   'data' => ['username'=>$model->username, 'test-name'=>'this is just for testing'],
                        ]);
                },
.....
```

everything in the data parameter should be send by post, but I only get the csrf token ..
thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 9):

use below code

```
echo Html::a('Name', ['controller/action'], [
    'class'=>'classname',
    'data'=>[
        'method'=>'post',
        'confirm'=>'Are you sure? OK to continue Retract..',
        'params'=>[
            'param1'=>'value',
            .......,
        ],
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 2):

"everything in the data parameter should be send by post" why do you believe that? I cannot find anything in the docs that anything in 'data' will be sent by post.
You can either:

1. use the get to send params OR
2. create a form and wrap it around the link. It should be sent by post.

Comment: update and delete actions send post id param. I do not want to use GET.  using a form is not efficient, have 1000 users would be 1000 forms...  there must be a way...

Comment: I think @MihaiP. 's first option is your best answer. Why is sending the required parameters via URL query params a problem? (i.e. GET params). Yii does this natively in gridviews delete buttons. Just an empty POST to [controller]/delete?id=[id].

Answer (score 0):

Try sent by session :

```
'buttons'=> [<br/>
    'password'=> function ($url, $model, $key){<br/>
     Yii::$app->session->set('username',$model->username);<br/>
     Yii::$app->session->set('test-name','this is just for testing');<br/>
    $url =$url = Url::toRoute(['users/reset-password', 'username' => $model->username]);<br/>
    return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>',$url,[<br/>
                   'title'=>'Clave',<br/>
                   'data-confirm' => Yii::t('yii', 'Are you sure you want to change this password?'),<br/>
                   'data-method' => 'post',<br/>

                        ]);
                },
```

On Controller call this :

You can get session :

```
Yii::$app->session->get('username');
```

And remove session

```
Yii::$app->session->remove('username');
```

Comment: Whoever upvoted this? This cannot possibly work, as the session is being set in the code which runs when the button is being generated, not clicked.